# Apache Server with PHP/MySQL on a Thumbdrive

Tags: apache-2.2, usb-flash-drive

What's the easiest way to configure an apache-server (Running PHP/MySQL) to run on a thumbdrive? I've seen solutions that claim to do this effortlessly, but I've not had much experience with them. From the experience here, which solution is best for somebody who wants casual access for personal-use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the [XAMPP portable app](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp) to be pretty easy to install and use

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Server2go](http://www.server2go-web.de/index.html) (Apache/PHP/Mysql):

> Server2Go is a Webserver that runs out of the box without any installation and on write protected media. This means that web applications based on Server2Go can be used directly from cdrom, a usb stick or from any folder on a hard disk without the hassle of configuring Apache, PHP or MySQL.
>   Server2Go allows you to create a standalone working web site or PHP application on a CD-ROM. There are many examples of its possible useses such as catalogue software, calculation programmes, image campaigns (CMS-based), computer based training lessons or other applicatons. Most PHP-Software such as the content management system Joomla or the computer based training software Moodle can be used from CD-ROM with the help of Server2Go.